# Inline code and shiny, is it possible?

Tags: shiny

I am trying to create a summary page of my network in a tab I've created on shiny. 
I was wondering if inline code works in shiny the way it does with Rmarkdown?

For example, if it were an Rmarkdown file it would be:
There are `r length(nodes2$id)` nodes in the network

I want to be able to show the figure without actually explicitly writing it, for instance I don't want:
'There are 48 nodes in the network'

So in future if more nodes are added to the network, it will automatically change.
If it doesn't work, is there an alternative way I can use?

I hope this question makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat html tag (here I use `h3()`) commands just like you would in regular R syntax:

```
h3(paste("There are",length(nodes2$id), "nodes in the network.", sep = " "))
```

Otherwise, you could write your Shiny app in Rmarkdown if you're more comfortable there.